# Explanation of the statement below about Groovy closures.

Tags: groovy

I'm reading this: `A closure looks a lot like a regular Java or Groovy code block, but actually it's not the same. The code within a regular code block (whether its a method block, static block, synchronized block, or just a block of code) is executed by the virtual machine as soon as it's encountered. With closures the statements within the curly brackets are not executed until the call() is made on the closure. In the previous example the closure is declared in line, but it's not executed at that time. It will only execute if the call() is explicitly made on the closure`

And I'm thinking, how is this true, in Java if you have an instance method, the code is only executed when the method is called then how are they saying above that is executed by the VM as soon as it sees it ? 
If I have a method `func(){int a =5; return a+5;}` this will be executed only when called is my understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description might be better taken with just synchronized block or regular scope braces.  What it's attempting to show is that when the thread of execution hits a regular code block, it continues on executing the contents.  With closure definitions, the code in the block is not immediately executed - it's used to define/instantiate a closure object (say, clos) which contains that logic, and which can be later executed via clos.call() (or just clos()).

example:

```
def x = 1

synchronized(this) {
    x = 1000
}
println x //x == 1000
```

vs.

```
def x = 1

Closure clos = { 
    x = 1000
}
println x // x == 1
clos()  // or clos.call()
println x // x == 1000
```

W/R/T method/static blocks: It's unclear to me if there is some nuanced way in which "encountered" and "executed" can be used in a JVM context that makes that part of the statement correct, but for practical purposes, it's at best misleading.  Methods are still only executed when called, and not by virtue of their declarations being located in the apparent path of code execution, as the following can be run in groovyConsole to show:

```
def x = 1

void methodA() {
    x = 1000
}

def b = {
    x = x + 1

}

println x // x is still 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another analogy, which is not necessarily technically accurate, is to think about Closures as anonymous inner classes that have a single method (the body of the closure).

Doing either closure.call() or closure() (short-hand for call()), invokes that single method.

Closures have additional features, of course, but I think that this is a good way to think about the basics.